# NERDTree is not displayed in buffer list

Tags: vimrc, buffers, plugin-nerdtree

I'm currently exploring ways to iterate through all buffers in vim and am confused by the behavior of `NERDTree`.

I displayed the `NERDTree` directory tree and expected that the viewport is bound to some buffer. But the `:ls` command did not show the buffer that is diplayed in the `NERDTree`'s viewport:

[image]

Is the viewport on which NERDTree displays the directory tree bound to some buffer? If no, how does NERDTree display the content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NERDTree does a great many things that are... unvim-like... in order to give the IDE “project drawer” experience. I consider most of them hacks, and I’m wary of a plugin which has to hack around default behaviors and usages to do something I don’t need (see [Oil and Vinegar](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/)).

All of that said, one of its hacks is actually quite normal—it’s an unlisted buffer (I believe). You can check the `'buftype'` option, or use `:ls!`.

Netrw actually does similar things most of the time, regarding unlisting buffers. It’s convenient not to have “non-file” buffers not appear in the regular buffer list.